# $\liminf A_n$ and $\limsup B_n$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Show that for a sequences of sets $A_n$ and $B_n$

$\liminf A_n\cap\limsup B_n \subset\limsup(A_n\cap B_n)$

Can you give some hint please.How can ı show this question.

Thank you

Comment: You call $A_n$ and $B_n$ "real sequences". Don't you mean that both $(A_n)_n$ and $(B_n)_n$ are sequences of subsets of $\mathbb R$? If not then what is meant by $A_n\cap B_n$?

Comment: You mean that $A_n$ and $B_n$ are sequences of sets otherwise their cut wouldn't be defined.

Comment: Yes, I mean that An and Bn are sequences of sets

Comment: First hint: write out what $\liminf A_n$ and $\limsup B_n$ mean. Second hint: go to the help link to learn how to format mathematics so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in\liminf A_{n}\cap\limsup B_{n}$.

$x\in\liminf A_{n}$ tells us that some $n_{0}\in\mathbb{N}$ exists
such that $n\geq n_{0}\implies x\in A_{n}$

$x\in\limsup B_{n}$ tells us that a sequence $\left(n_{k}\right)$
exists in $\mathbb{N}$ with $n_{1}<n_{2}<\cdots$ and $x\in B_{n_{k}}$
for each $k$.

We can choose $n_{1}\geq n_{0}$ and then also $x\in A_{n_{k}}\cap B_{n_{k}}$
for each $k$, telling us that...

Comment: You are very welcome.